# How to use rdiff-backup with unicode file names?

Tags: rdiff-backup

I am using `rdiff-backup` to backup Windows Server 2012 to a Raspberry Pi.

Raspberry Pi has a USB-attached 2TB NTFS drive.

In general all works well: Except when `rdiff-backup` comes across folders with french accents (e.g è) in the name, in which point it fails with:

> Making directory /data/Am▒lie
>   Sending back exception [Errno 84] Invalid or incomplete multibyte or wide character: '/data/Am\xe9lie' of type : E

The command I am using, on the Windows Server, is:
`rdiff-backup --terminal-verbosity 8 --print-statistics c:\. pi@mypi.local::/media/pi/backupdrive/data`

How do I get rdiff-backup to backup folder/filenames with utf-8 encoding?

EDIT: The issue is with the Pi->NTFS drive, not WindowsSever->Pi.
  (If I run the same command to an ext4 partition, it works fine)

Comment: It seems that you'd need to convert the encoding between whatever Windows Server is using and whatever the pi thinks the NTFS drive that it has mounted is using.  Is the NTFS drive on the pi mounted with the `utf8` option?

Comment: Thanks. I've mounted with "-o iocharset=utf8".  This works fine in that I can directly create files with unicode names on the NTFS drive, from the RPi.  However, when running rdiff-backup, it fails on the same filenames.  If I run rdiff-backup to an ext4 drive, then it works fine. So I am confused.